# Lite wind/air libraries

Tags: background, air, wind

Hey guys, I notice myself using a few of the same lite wind/breeze files in my BGs for day and night time scenes. I mean I have enough to get by but I would like to know if anyone knew of any libraries that  consited of just very low key exterior airs, no birds, not crazy blowing and whistling. Just clean low level exterior airs for calm day and night scenes.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Try Mountain Air: http://www.tonsturm.com/Soundpacks/files/Mountain_Air.html

And/or layer some textures from the Blow Tools set.  Those have some good textures to work with.

Comment: I have mountain air it's just there's a lot of birds, and I like to have control of birds and air seperately, but I'll deffinatly peep the blow tools. Sounds like I'm making fun of pro tools, haha any ways thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: I second Blow Tools! 

Comment: The other idea is to go and record some - usually the afternoon is a good time on a warm day if you can find a place devoid of crickets, pine forests tend to give you a nice "wash" presence.  It has to do with convection I believe which results in the wind patterns which help create the forest presence, wherein it's too cold in AM so everything sounds too still.  In Blow Tools try searching "breeze" and "rush", there's some good ones in there then just knock em down so they play low.

Answer (score 1):

Hi

I have lots of 'empty-space' records, interior and ext. It's not completed for a collection yet but most of them are finish prepared, 3-4 minutes long. Ext. tracks were recorded in the mountains and have different colors of 'nothing'. Interior tracks all are room tones,  about 2 minutes long. Some of them sounds more electric, others more ventilation, industrial, or simply almost nothing for the background. If you are interested send me a mail at: https://www.soundeffects.ch/ I can send you some mp3 for previews and a tracklist from what I have.
Just for preview, some industrial roomtones you can preview at: https://www.soundeffects.ch/advanced-sound-effects-search.php?soundeffects=room&soundcategory=&library=Industrial+Soundscapes&type=
These tracks are form my Industrial Soundscapes collection, the factory hall tracks are no-silent tracks with activity in the background, the roomtone tracks should be empty.

Send me a note

Best
Guido

Comment: Cool! I'm into that. I like coming across independent libraries, cus I hate hearing things I have used a lot in movies. I'll drop you a line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe these will help you.

https://getsoundeffects.com/#/products-page/sound-bundles/atmosphere/

https://getsoundeffects.com/#/products-page/sound-bundles/graveyard-ambience/

https://getsoundeffects.com/#/products-page/sound-bundles/space-ambience/

Comment: Awesome I'll check these out! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There has recently been a Audio Plugin/VSTi which has been created called AudioWind and AudioRain. It's basically a customizable plugin which creates basically infinite combinations of wind samples and or rain samples. It's fairly new, but it's pretty neat and has lots of potential.

Comment: Wow, this actually seems quite useful. Anyone have practical experience on it yet? http://www.audiogaming.net/audiowind-audiorain

Comment: I'm working on something now, will get back to everyone as soon as.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great list. I've been clamoring for the same thing lately, but am trying to keep my expenses down. So rather than searching for new libraries I've been scouring through my own AMB files, listening in between all the "polluting noise" and tossing on a heaping of C4 & EQ to minimize the sounds that I don't want and maximize the tones that I am looking for. I've had some successes, but at the cost of time. This is thinking I should invest more wisely.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do some tracks in Kyma, where I controlled the pitch and filtering with a Wacom pen for a more natural feel. This way I could get the gusts etc. when I need them , and in sync with picture, if needed.

Here is a few fast ones, used in fishermans tv documentary, I did some sfx recordings for:

http://snd.sc/PvGuUJ

http://snd.sc/PvGUdA

All dry recordings. Mixing the different layers, automating the volume, and adding some verb, makes them really useful, I think.

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 0):

I've found GRM's reson useful for creating interesting wind effects.  Really seems to liven up a boring wind track.

Mikkel, how are you filtering your wind tracks in Kyma?  I bought kyma a few months ago and am always looking for cool uses for it.  Thanks.

Comment: The wind is not wind, its a noise sample, which runs through a FreqLow prototype controlled via the X pen on the Wacom, and a OctSpacing prototype controlled by the Y pen. I have then put in a gain prototype which is controlled by the Z pen (pressure). This makes is easy to both stop and start the "wind" and to add or subtract volume to the sample. (hope Im making sense).

Comment: I think so.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll give it a try.